# PHP getting days of a month for a database

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop

I'm making a calender planner with php/css/javascript/html.

I am trying to set each day of the month a class which is "day". I tried using the following:

```
**PHP CODE**
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$jobNameValue ='';
$monthDays = '';
$monthname = '';
$days = '';
//getting values for job names

$sql_job_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs");
$num_job_name = mysql_num_rows($sql_job_name);
if($num_job_name >0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_job_name)) {
        $job_name = $row["job_name"];
        $job_short_name = $row["job_short_name"];
        $jobNameValue .= '<option value="' . $job_short_name . '">' . $job_name . '</option>';
    }
} else {
    $jobNameValue .= '<option value="NULL">No job listed</option>';
}
//getting values for months days
$sql_month_days = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM months");
$num_month_days = mysql_num_rows($sql_month_days);
if($sql_month_days > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_month_days)) {
        $month_id = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["name"]; 
        $num_days = $row["num_days"];if($num_days === "31") {
   for($i=1; $i <=31; $i++) { 
      $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
   }
} else { 
    if($num_days === "30") {
       for($i=1; $i <=30; $i++) { 
          $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
       }
     } else { 
         if($num_days === "29") {
           for($i=1; $i <=29; $i++) { 
             $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
           }
         }
       }
  }
    $monthDays .= '<div id="monthContainer">
                        <span class="monthName">'. $name .'</span>
                        <div class="monthDaysContainter">
                            '. $days.'
                        </div>
                   </div>';
}

}


**HTML CODE**
<div id="container">
    <div ="newJob">
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" id="newJobForm">
            <label for="jobName">Job Name:</label>
                <select id="jobName">
                    <?php echo $jobNameValue; ?>
                </select>
            <input type="date">
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="calander">
        <?php echo $monthDays; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does not work correctly, it kept duplicating every month and I am not sure how to correctly right the php to achieve what was intended.

I am only a beginner at php so I am not good at the moment

Could anyone help me with this?

If there any more information you need, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you in advance!
Chris

Comment: If duplication of months is the problem, you'll have to add the code for it.

Comment: Post the rest of your code, what you have above shouldn't give you duplicates, and you can easily make that one for loop using for($i=1; $i<=$num_days; $i++)

Comment: Where do you get $num_days from here?

Comment: @shannonman I first tried that before adding the ifs, but that sill did not work. I will update my code now. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating the whole thing in the while loop, so the days that are appended from the last call are also appended to the next output.

```
$tmpArray = array();
if($sql_month_days > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_month_days)) {
        array_push($tmpArray, $row);
    }
}
foreach($tmpArray as $k){
    $monthDays .= '<div id="monthContainer"><span class="monthName">'. $k['name'] .'</span><div class="monthDaysContainter">'. calNumDays($k['num_days']).'</div></div>';
}
```

**Update**

Should you wish to keep what you already have

```
if($num_days === "31") {
    $days = '';
    for($i=1; $i <=31; $i++) {
        $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
    }
} else { 
if($num_days === "30") {
    $days = '';
   for($i=1; $i <=30; $i++) { 
      $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
   }
 } else { 
     if($num_days === "29") {
         $days = '';
       for($i=1; $i <=29; $i++) { 
         $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
       }
     }
   }
}
```

You only really to need to reinitialize the `$days` before each `for` after the `if`

Comment: I had an Fatal error: Cannot redeclare calNumDays() And it only shown up to 29 dates, and only repeated once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have this error now Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. Do you have any idea what and why this warning has came up? Thank you for the response

Comment: sorry is forgot to add the $tmpArray = array(); to initialize the array my apoligies.

Comment: Ah thanks, that error has gone now, Only one thing, The days haven't shown up. I am really great full for this. Thank you!

Comment: are you still echoing $monthDays in the html?

Comment: @unasAquila Why are you re-declaring the same variable 3 times?

Comment: @mattedgod because if you don't redeclare for each iteration then the $days of the last would be appened to the new $days.

Comment: @unasAquila Thanks! The updated code worked! Yeah the code was a little complex for my understand and the new updated code much easier to under stand! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try just doing this and seeing if that fixes it, you don't need all of those `if` statements

```
for($i=1; $i <= $num_days; $i++) { 
   $days .= '<span class="day">' . $i . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: I tired this before, this still duplicated the months. I will post the full code now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

do not use `===`,use `==`,maybe your `$num_days` is integer

Comment: Yeah I have tried using == and === all with the same outcome. I believe $num_days is an int, what should I change it too and would it make a difference.

Comment: @ChrisAtwood i know,i guess you didn't clear `$days`,please reset the `$days` at the beginning of the `while`